# rand () - get result for 10 rand values of each id

Tags: mysql

I have query as follows:

```
select s.name, m.c_id, m.r_stat, m.l_upd, m.desc, c.email 
from manual m 
join selling s 
join contact c 
on m.id=s.id 
and m.id=c.id 
where c.id in (21,22) order by rand() limit 10;
```

I want to have the record of 10 for each id 21 & 22.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Is this join syntax correct on MySql?

Comment: select s.name, m.c_id, m.r_stat, m.l_upd, m.desc, c.email
from manual m
join selling s
join contact c 
on m.id=s.id
and m.id=c.id
where c.id in (21,22) order by rand() limit 10;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use variables:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select s.name, m.c_id, m.r_stat, m.l_upd, m.desc, c.email,
           @rn := IF(@id = c.id,
                     @rn + 1,
                     IF(@id := c.id, 1, 1)
                    ) as rn
    from manual m
    join selling s
      on m.id=s.id 
    join contact c
      on m.id=c.id
    cross join ( SELECT @rn := 0, @id := 0) as vars
    where c.id in (21,22) 
    order by c.id, rand()
   ) as t
where rn <= 10

;
```

Comment: Here I'm getting one more filed called "rn", if I dont want this filed to be shown then how could i do that!

Comment: instead of `SELECT *` write the fields you need `select s.name, m.c_id, m.r_stat, m.l_upd, m.desc, c.email,`